# Uninstalling applications using tools disables program features on next install

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, shortcuts, uninstall

After completing my project i have developed the Installer using visual studio 2015. I have two custom actions associated with this installer(one is called after success dialogue of installation and the second one is after the uninstall completed). The custom action on installing will creates shortcut to the desktop and startup and the one which I called after uninstalling will remove it as well. Note There are more operations in this custom actions.Everything working fine as expected in all versions of Windows.

Later i have used some tool(say `Revo` Uninstaller) for performing uninstall operation, it successfully uninstalled the application and associated references from the system. Then i have restarted the  system and try installing the application again it installed fine and created the icons in the desktop and start menu.

But Clicking on that desktop shortcut icon not opening the specified target, and also application icon is not showing in the system try but it is running in the background(checked in task manager).

When i double click on the shortcut the following window will be popped.
[image]

What may be the reason with this external uninstaller?

Comment: It looks you have hidden the icon. So we cannot even see if the shortcut is valid. What does it show in Shortcut properties?

Comment: Just a curiosity: did it really do a cold restart or did the OS takes some advantage from an hybrid hibernation?

Comment: @AEonAX: When i check the properties of the shortcut it is showing the target location, i have tried opening target location that too worked, it opens the specified directory